# How do i import single object from django to a html template

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-queryset

i am creating a website with django and i have 2 models in it,1:Gifi(contains .gif images) and 2:categorite! When i click one of the .gif images i want to be sent to another html template where that image shows and information about it.I have done some coding and when i click the image i get to the html page but the problem is that no data from django gets imported to that html page,except the id on the url.I know the problem is so simple but i am new to this and i dont know the code.

This is the models:

```
from django.db import models

class categorite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Gifi(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='website/static/')
    emri = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Kodet = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    categoryId = models.ForeignKey(categorite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import  Gifi,categorite
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'website/home.html')

def categories(request):
    content = {
        'view': categorite.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'website/categories.html',content)

def PostaCode(request):
    return render(request, 'website/PostaCode.html')

def Contact(request):
    return render(request, 'website/Contact.html')
def category(request,id):
    content = {
        'view':  Gifi.objects.filter(categoryId_id=id),
    }
    return render(request, 'website/category.html',content)

def code(request,id):
    content = {
        'view':  get_object_or_404(Gifi,pk=id)
    }
    return render(request, 'website/code.html',content)
```

This is the template where i click the image:

```
{% for gifi in view %}

         <a href="{% url 'code' gifi.id %}" class="gif">

    <img src="/static/{{gifi.foto}}" id="foto" alt="" >
      <p id="source">Source: {{gifi.Source}}</p>
      <p id="permbatjaa">Coding: {{gifi.Kodet}}</p>
    </a>


{% endfor %}
```

This is the template where i need to get to, and where information about image should be(code.html):

```
 <img src="/static/{{gifi.foto}}" id="foto" alt="" >
        <p>{{gifi.emri}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is passed a few days so you might get an answer already but Django's view function and the template are so simple, and you could write:
The `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Categorite(models.Model):
    # id field is already exists models.Model not necessary
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Gifi(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='website/static/')
    emri = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    kodet = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gifis')
```

And the `views.py`:

```
def category(request, id):
    # For the foreign key fields _id field auto created also
    objs = Gifi.objects.filter(category_id=id)  
    return render(request, 'website/category.html', {'gifis': objs})


def code(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Gifi, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'website/code.html', {'gifi': obj})
```

And the template `website/category.html`

```
  {% for gifi in gifis %}
    <a href="{% url 'code' gifi.id %}" class="gif">
      <img src="/static/{{gifi.foto}}" id="foto" alt="" >
      <p id="source">Source: {{gifi.source}}</p>
      <p id="permbatjaa">Coding: {{gifi.kodet}}</p>
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
```

And the template `website/code.html`

```
<img src="/static/{{gifi.foto}}" id="foto" alt="" >
<p>{{gifi.emri}}</p>
```

To meet [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) spec, under_score recommended for the variable names, and CamelCase is recommended for the class names.
If you are new to Django, I highly recommend the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/) page would help a lot.